# Php preg_replace replace all matching content between two tags, except content contained in another two specific tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this html:

```
(text)Text one(/text)(text)text two(/text)<input type="text" name="name" 
id="name" value="(text)text three(/text)" />(text)Text four(/text)
```

I want to replace the words and relative (text) (/text) tags contained between (text) and (/text) except that contained inside an input/textarea value.

I want to use regex, not dom

Actually I'm using:

```
preg_replace("~\\(text\)[\s\S]+?\\(\/text\)~","replacing text",$content);
```

But this one replace all, also content inside inputs/textareas

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique to match the `<input...>` tag and disqualify it for replacement.  This will allow all of the `(text)...(/text)` substrings to be replaced as intended.

[Pattern&Replacement Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UaS746/1)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/11iB3))

```
$html=<<<HTML
(text)Text one(/text)(text)text two(/text)<input type="text" name="name" 
id="name" value="(text)text three(/text)" />(text)Text four(/text)
HTML;

echo preg_replace('~<input[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\(text\).*?\(/text\)~','[*]',$html);
```

Output:

```
[*][*]<input type="text" name="name" 
id="name" value="(text)text three(/text)" />[*]
```

---

...now for the *fine print*:

- Regex is generally unadvisable for parsing html because it will work until suddenly/silently it doesn't work due to a fringe case / anomaly in the input string itself.  An html parser like DomDocument is often the recommended tool.
- I am not sure if you are doing any dynamic replacement text or if all of the replacements are receiving the same static value.  If you need to perform a dynamic replacement, `preg_replace_callback()` is likely to be the best tool for the job.
- My pattern is very much designed to accommodate your input string.  Depending on the variability of the data in your actual project, the pattern may need to be refined/adjusted.
- My pattern uses `.*?` between `(text)` and `(/text)` to allow for the possibility of a `(` character.  If you *KNOW* there will not be a `(` in these relative locations you can improve pattern efficiency with `[^(]*` instead.  The opposite is also true of the `[^>]+` inside the input tag portion -- if your project data contains a `>` in these tags, then you can use `.*?` but at a loss of efficiency.