# preg_replace: UBB Code [textarea] - do not replace \n by <br> within tags [textarea][/textarea]

Tags: php, preg-replace

So I wanted to enable UBB Code on my Website using preg_replace

```
$text = $dbentry['text'];

$bbformat = array(
"/\\r?\\n/i" => "<br>",
"/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/i" => "<i>$1</i>",
"/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/i" => "<div align=\"center\"><center><table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\"><tr bgcolor=\"magenta\"><td>Codeblock:</td></tr><tr><td><form><textarea rows=\"10\" cols=\"82\">$1</textarea></form></td></tr></table></center></div>",
....
);

foreach($bbformat as $match=>$replacement){
$text = preg_replace($match, $replacement, $text);
}

echo $text;
```

This works, however, it replaces text between two [code][/code] elements too, resulting in <br> or <i></i> codes in the textarea, where they do not belong:

[image]

I would like to skip any text that is between [code][/code] UBB elements and output the raw text as it is stored in the DB:

[image]

How can this be achieved in PHP?

I actually tried `"/\[code\][^>]+\[\/code\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\r?\\n/i" => "<br>",` (which I read of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983149/php-preg-replace-replace-all-matching-content-between-two-tags-except-content-c)) with the result, that the latter argument `"/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/i"` to replace `[code][/code]` itself with `<textarea></textarea>` is also skipped and the output on the website is `[code]bl \n ah[i]test[/i][/code]` instead of `<textarea>bl \n ah[i]test[/i]</textarea>`. I could workaround this by adding these two arguments to the array:

```
"/\[code\]/i" => "<div align=\"center\"><center><table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\"><tr bgcolor=\"magenta\"><td>Codeblock:</td></tr><tr><td><form><textarea rows=\"10\" cols=\"82\">",
"/\[\/code\]/i" => "</textarea></form></td></tr></table></center></div>",
```

This replaces [code] and [/code] on each own with the unsexy result that the website looks like garbage if someone forgets to write [/code]. Looks like that the condition `"/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/i"` is no longer valid within the same array due to (*SKIP)(*FAIL) why replacing each on its own works?

There must be a better solution...what am I missing?

Comment: your issue is in the first pic or the second one?

Comment: issue is in the first one. there are no actual line breaks (\n) in the textarea, but <br> tags. i want to exclude the text between [code][/code] from being replaced by preg_replace. is (*SKIP)(*FAIL) a solution? how would it look like?

Comment: i actually tried
`"/\[code\][^>]+\[\/code\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\r?\\n/i" => "<br>",`
with the result, that the textare respectively [code]blah[/code] part is not output at all.

Comment: why not just `\str_replace('<br>', "\n", $string)` ?

Comment: str_replace back to \n would not solve the problem, that someone who wrote `[code]For italics text you need to write [i]test[/i][code]` would end up with the output `<textarea>For italics text you need to write <i>test</i></textarea>`. 

I really need to exclude anything between [code] and [code] from being replaced, so it is output like this: `<textarea>For italics text you need to write [i]test[/i]</textarea>`. 

`"/\[code\][^>]+\[\/code\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\r?\\n/i" => "<br>",` actually works, but it also ignores the latter `"/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/i" => "<textarea>$1</textarea>"`condit.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with one string each time, preg_replace does not know about the UBB, so it will replace all `\n` occurrences to `<br />`, the only way I can see is to use using PHP is something like [`preg_replace_callback_array`](https://php.netpreg_replace_callback_array).

```
$bbformat = array(
    "/\\r?\\n/i" => function ($m) {
        return "<br>";
    },
    "/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/i" => function ($m) {
        return "<i>".$m[1]."</i>";
    },
    "/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/i" => function ($m) {
    return "<div align=\"center\"><center><table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\"><tr bgcolor=\"magenta\"><td>Codeblock:</td></tr><tr><td><form><textarea rows=\"10\" cols=\"82\">".str_replace("<br>", "\n", $m[1])."</textarea></form></td></tr></table></center></div>";
    },
);

$text = preg_replace_callback_array($bbformat, $text);

echo $text;
```

but as you can see, you must re-replace the `<br>` to `\n` again which may consume a lot of memory in some cases.

however, you can play around with regex itself to exclude the `\n` => `<br>` replacement if the occurrence is not between the `[code]` block by changing your first pattern from `/\\r?\\n/i` to: `/\\r?\\n+(?![^\[].*\])/i` or even `/\\r?\\n+(?![^\[code\]].*\[\/code\])/i` if you want to keep your `[code]` block

so your final code may look like this:

```
$bbformat = array(
"/\\r?\\n+(?![^\[code\]].*\[\/code\])/i" => "<br>",
"/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/i" => "<i>$1</i>",
"/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/i" => "<div align=\"center\"><center><table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\"><tr bgcolor=\"magenta\"><td>Codeblock:</td></tr><tr><td><form><textarea rows=\"10\" cols=\"82\">$1</textarea></form></td></tr></table></center></div>",
);

foreach($bbformat as $match=>$replacement){
$text = preg_replace($match, $replacement, $text);
}

echo $text;
```

Comment: thank you, i will check your solution respectively preg callback.